Markov versus Martingale
My text provides an illuminating example about the fact that Markov processes are not martingales in general and martingales are not Markov processes in general.
First, the standard brownian motion $(B_t,t\geq 0)$ enjoys both properties.
Next, consider brownian motion with a drift $(X_t,t\geq 0)$, where $X_t = \sigma B_t + \mu t$. This is Markov, but not a martingale. Consider the conditional MGF :
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{aX_t}|\mathcal{F}_s] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{a\sigma B_t + a\mu t}|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&= e^{a\mu t} \mathbb{E}[e^{a\sigma B_t}|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&= e^{a\mu t} \mathbb{E}[e^{a\sigma (B_t - B_s + B_s)}|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
& \{ B_s \text{ is }\mathcal{F}_s-\text{ measurable }\}\\
&= e^{a\mu t} e^{a\sigma B_s} \mathbb{E}[e^{a\sigma (B_t - B_s)}|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
& \{ (B_t - B_s) \perp \mathcal{F}_s\}\\
&= e^{a\mu t} e^{a\sigma B_s} \mathbb{E}[e^{a\sigma (B_t - B_s)}]\\
&= e^{a\mu t} e^{a\sigma B_s} e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2\sigma^2 (t-s)}\\
&= e^{a (\mu s + \sigma B_s)} e^{a \mu(t-s) + \frac{1}{2}a^2\sigma^2 (t-s)} \\
&= e^{a X_s} e^{(a \mu + \frac{1}{2}a^2\sigma^2)(t-s)} 
\end{align}
So, the conditional MGF is only a function of $t-s$ and the position of the process at time $s$, $X(s)$. So, it is Markov.
Let $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(X_s,s \leq t)$ be the sigma algebra generated by the process $(X_t)t\in\mathbb{R}$. For any $s < t$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s] &= \mathbb{E}[\sigma B_t + \mu t|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&= \sigma \mathbb{E}[B_t | \mathcal{F}_s] + \mu t\\
&= \sigma B_s + \mu t\\
&= \sigma B_s + \mu s + \mu(t-s)\\
&= X_s + \mu(t-s)\\
&\neq X_s
\end{align*}
So, $(X_t,t\geq 0)$ is not a martingale.
Finally, consider $X_s = \int_0^s B_u dB_u$ and $Y_t = \int_0^t X_s dB_s$. The process $(Y_t,t\geq 0)$ is a martingale, but not Markov.
Since $(X_s,s\geq 0)$ is square integrable, adapted and continuous, the Ito integral $\int_0^t X_s dB_s$ is well defined. So, by the properties of Ito integral, $(Y_t,t\geq 0)$ is a martingale.
How do I prove that the process $(Y_t,t\geq 0)$ is NOT markov?

I didn't stud such things since long time. But as far as I remember, as far as a stochastic integral is well defined, it's necessarily a Markov process (see theorem 7.2.4 of the book SDE of Oksendal of the 6th edition)

If a process increment at t implies usage of data for s<t it not Markov, which demands  $$d X_t | F_{s<t} = d X_t | F_t $$ or, in words, future is independent of past if present is known.

By Ito's formula, $X_t={1\over 2}(B_t^2-t)$ and $Y_t={1\over 6}B^3_t-{t\over 2}B_t$.
Therefore, for $0<s<t$, leting $\Delta$ denote $B_t-B_s$ (so that $\Delta$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$),
$$
\eqalign{
Y_t &= {1\over 6}\Delta^3+{1\over 2}\Delta ^2\cdot B_s+{1\over 2}\Delta \cdot B^2_s+{1\over 6}B^3_s-{t\over 2}\Delta-{t\over 2}B_s\cr
&=Y_s +\left[3\Delta^2-{t-s\over 2}\right]B_s+{1\over 2}\Delta \cdot B_s^2+{1\over 6}\Delta^3-{t\over 2}\Delta\cr
}
$$
From this it's clear that the conditional distribution of $Y_t$, given $\mathcal F_s$ depends not only on $Y_s$ but also on $B_s$ and $B_s^2$. Thus $(Y_t)$ is not Markov with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$ generated by the Brownian motion $(B_t)$.
Whether $(Y_t)$ is Markov with respect to its own filtration $\mathcal F_t^Y:=\sigma\{Y_s: 0\le s\le t\}$ is also in doubt, because the map $B_t\mapsto {1\over 6}B^3_t-{t\over 2}B_t$ is not one-to-one.
